# Game Center voice chat ducks sound

Tags: ios, voip, game-center, gamekit

I've a multiplayer game where I'm creating a Game Center voice channel and both players join the channel. However, as soon as both players are in the channel, Game Center ducks my background music.
This already happens when the channel is created and nobody talks (I have a push to talk model).

Does anybody know how I can prevent that from happening. I'm fine with Game Center ducking the rest of the sound when somebody actually speaks but I don't want all sounds going noticeably down in gain just because there's a chance that somebody talks.

Comment: No, it is a bug in Game Center I'm afraid. I've filed a bug report to Apple (12556082) but it's still marked as open.